# Apply a stylesheet for both print and screen

Tags: html, css, media-queries

How can I set a CSS file for print & screen?

I tried to set both values on the tag (like for a class attribute) but it doesn't work:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen print">
```

The question goes also for CSS in body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a comma:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, print">
```

> The question goes also for CSS in body.

If you're referring to the `style` attribute, this cannot be done because you can't embed media queries in inline styles.

Comment: Ah! There you go, I feel stupid asking a question so simple but I swear I couldn't find it on google or SO (and I searched!)

Comment: @Matthieu: That's OK - you can always refer to the spec, in particular the Media Queries spec is an easy read with plenty of examples: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries